# iOS Bluetooth connectivity Pop-ups

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

When we initiate CBCentralManager, iOS throws two kinds of pop-ups

1. Bluetooth is not enabled in Settings
   [Turn On Bluetooth to allow "APP_NAME" to connect to Accessories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QTso.png)
2. Bluetooth is enabled in Settings and turned off in Control center (for new connections)
   ["APP_NAME" would like to use Bluetooth for new connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRuSf.png)

For Beacon search, we need Bluetooth connection but iPhone doesn't need to connect to peripherals. So, We want to restrict presenting second prompt.

Can we prevent displaying prompt for new connections?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not fixable in iOS 13. Initializing CBCentralManager permits connections, so it will behave as though you are going to make them. It will not appear if you use iBeacons via CLLocationManager, but I assume you are only scanning for other types of beacons.

Comment: Thanks, Rob for your reply. I am using both iBeacon and CBCentralManager to connect two kinds of peripherals.